# GaussianBlur and optimization for gpu using openMP and CV

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, openmp

So im working through openMP trying to research about whether a cpu or gpu will run image blurring faster/slower/or moderately the relative. From what I think a gpu should run it a bit faster because gpu's perform small operations relatively quick correct? As a cpu can perform complex operations at a reasonable time:

So here is the code I'm using to test it:

```
IplImage* gaussian_blur_parallel(IplImage* image, double r) {
    IplImage* result = cvCloneImage(image);
    int h = image->height;
    int w = image->width;

    double rs = ceil(r * 2.57);     // significant radius
    std::clock_t    start;
    start = std::clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided) num_threads(4)

    for(int i=0; i<h; i++) {
    int current_num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
std::cout<<"threads"<<current_num_threads<<std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            Weights weights;
            for(int iy = i-rs; iy<i+rs+1; iy++) {
                for (int ix = j - rs; ix < j + rs + 1; ix++) {
                    int x = myMin(w - 1, myMax(0, ix));
                    int y = myMin(h - 1, myMax(0, iy));
                    double dsq = (ix - j) * (ix - j) + (iy - i) * (iy - i);
                    double wght = exp(-dsq / (2 * r * r)) / (PI * 2 * r * r);
                    CvScalar channels = cvGet2D(image, y, x);

                    // calculate the value for each channel
                    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                        weights.value[c] += channels.val[c] * wght;
                        weights.weight[c] += wght;
                    }
                }
            }

            // set the value for each channel in the resulting image.
//            printf("i=%d, j=%d, r=%f, g=%f, b=%f\n", i, j, weights.value[0], weights.value[1], weights.value[2]);
            CvScalar resultingChannels = cvGet2D(result, i, j);
            for(int c=0; c < 3; c++) {
                resultingChannels.val[c] = round(weights.value[c] / weights.weight[c]);
                weights.value[c] = 0.0;
                weights.weight[c] = 0.0;
            }
            cvSet2D(result, i, j, resultingChannels);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

from what im seeing in the documentation, anything ran in the inside that pragma comment should be doing work on a gpu correct?

however if I do it without the pragma comment(Im assuming this is the cpu working..)

```
IplImage* gaussian_blur(IplImage* image, double r) {
    IplImage* result = cvCloneImage(image);
    int h = image->height;
    int w = image->width;
    printf("h=%d, w=%d", h, w);
    double rs = ceil(r * 2.57);     // significant radius
    std::clock_t    start;
    start = std::clock();
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            Weights weights;
            for(int iy = i-rs; iy<i+rs+1; iy++) {
                for (int ix = j - rs; ix < j + rs + 1; ix++) {
                    int x = myMin(w - 1, myMax(0, ix));
                    int y = myMin(h - 1, myMax(0, iy));
                    double dsq = (ix - j) * (ix - j) + (iy - i) * (iy - i);
                    double wght = exp(-dsq / (2 * r * r)) / (PI * 2 * r * r);
                    CvScalar channels = cvGet2D(image, y, x);

                    // calculate the value for each channel
                    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                        weights.value[c] += channels.val[c] * wght;
                        weights.weight[c] += wght;
                    }
                }
            }

            // set the value for each channel in the resulting image.
//            printf("i=%d, j=%d, r=%f, g=%f, b=%f\n", i, j, weights.value[0], weights.value[1], weights.value[2]);
            CvScalar resultingChannels = cvGet2D(result, i, j);
            for(int c=0; c < 3; c++) {
                resultingChannels.val[c] = round(weights.value[c] / weights.weight[c]);
                weights.value[c] = 0.0;
                weights.weight[c] = 0.0;
            }
            cvSet2D(result, i, j, resultingChannels);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

The time for this to work is relatively the same as the gpu doing.

**So my question really is, is what i'm doing irrelevant and not really make much a difference for a gpu? IS it that im setting the clock in the wrong place? How can i check how many threads are being used properly in parallel in OpenMP?**

Comment: hi there.  I think your program may not be using the GPU, just extra threads.  How big is your image?  There is overhead in creating threads so if it's a small image you may not get any advantage.  What version of omp are you using?

Comment: We are using OMP 3.1, the image we're using is a 1920x1080, and i think you are correct. How can we necessarily tell if we're using the gpu itself instead of extra threads. I can post more code as well.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure OMP started supporting GPU in version 4.  My suggestion to you would be either to use CUDA (it's not much different from what you're doing...and there may be some example code that does something very similar) or check out openCV which has GPU connectivity.  What GPU do you have? Sometimes that will tell you your next step.

Comment: I just noticed that too moments before, i will try OMP v4 if not give cuda a try

Comment: Not to come off as a downer and there might be something I was overlooking, but I likewise looked into GPU implementations of gaussian blur (in my case using very large images, like 4kx4k+ with a blur radius often in the hundreds of pixels), and found I couldn't beat my CPU implementation (though that had a lot of optimization effort put in with SIMD and multithreading and tiled traversal of the image for locality of ref). What I found was that the GPU implementation outperformed the CPU one in cases with a very small blur radius, but the CPU implementation started outperforming it...

Comment: ... as the blur radius started to get large (ex: bigger than 20 pixels). That said, we also don't have the most powerful GPU and the code was hardly optimized to shreds, but got disappointing results there. My basic guess for it was that this nature in which the blur algorithm has to access neighboring pixels somehow wrecks the parallelism, since we did see initial improvements as long as the blur radius was very small. Our CPU version started getting an edge when the blur radius started getting quite large.

Comment: Yea I can see that could be a case, I upgraded to Version 4 and still there was no difference, the documentation doesnt have much insight on how to check, I printed all the threads it going between different threads atleast, but whether its using GPU or not im not sure. Im going to try OpenCL since im looking for both GPU and CPU runtimes, any suggestions for any other libs?

Comment: I'd use python + dask here's a good example: https://notebooks.anaconda.org/dask/parallelize_image_filtering_workload

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the wrong method to measure time. `std::clock` measures the CPU time, not the wall-clock time. You will never see a decrease of the value measured when you run multithreaded, unless some kind of superlinear speedup effect comes into play. Use `omp_get_wtime()` instead.

Second, the `parallel for` construct will **not** execute on an accelerator device unless nested within the scope of a `target` construct:

```
double start;
start = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp target ...
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided)
for(int i=0; i<h; i++) {
   ...
}

std::cout << "Time: " << (omp_get_wtime() - start) * 1000.0 << " ms" << std::endl;
```

Execution on GPUs and other accelerators with their own memory space requires proper setup of the data environment. This includes adding various `map` clauses to the `target` directive, which instruct the compiler to copy certain information onto the device before the execution and out of it after the offloaded region has finished. Take a look at the documentation of the `map` clause, then examine carefully all the variables used in the code and write the corresponding clauses.

Also, pay attention to the fact that all functions called from within the `target` region must be specifically marked with the `declare target` construct. That applies to functions like `cvGet2D()`, `cvSet2D()`, `myMin()`, and `myMax()`. If those are implemented as preprocessor macros, it is not necessary to declare them as target functions. Otherwise, the compiler won't generate versions callable on the device, which will result in errors.

Once all this is in place, you have to pass the right command-line options to the compiler in order to enable generation of target code. Also, make sure that your compiler supports GPU offloading. For example, the Intel compiler supports offloading to Intel Xeon Phi only. GCC should [support offloading](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading) to Intel Xeon Phi and NVIDIA GPUs in its latest incarnation, but seems to still have some issues. Your current best option for OpenMP offloading to NVIDIA GPUs is the PGI compiler suite. No idea what the situation with offloading to AMD GPUs is.